# How Much MB/Playthroughs do i need to complete the Remake System?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1, neptunia-rebirth-2, neptunia-rebirth-3

In the *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth* series there is the Remake System where you can spend materials and MB to complete plans such as getting new items, alter dungeons and changing how the game works (ie, break damage limit or destroy symbol attack).

I know that there a bunch of costly plans like the CPU Candidate Plans in *Re;Birth* and the Oracle Plans in *Re;Birth 2* as these can cost 1024 MB each and it's not possible to make them all in one play through so you need multiple playthroughs to get Memory Increase drops from events (ie, Bosses, Chipper events)

So with the 3 *Rebirth* Games. how much MB do you need to make every plan in the Remake System and how many playthroughs do you need to get that much?